# how can I run kubeadm command in GKE(google kubernetes engine)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I create cluster using GKE.
but there is not kube-apiserver Workloads in kube-system namespace
and there is not kubeadm executable file when I connecting master node using ssh.

But I create kubernetes using "kubeadm init" in GCE(google compute engine) VM
and there is kube-apiserver pod when run "kubectl get pods -n kube-system"
and there is installed kubeadm executable file.

I use standard-2 machine(2CPU, 7.5G) for both case.

I want to control GKE(google kubernetes engine) using kubeadm command.

Answer (score 1):

GKE is a managed Kubernetes cluster, hence you don't have actual control over the master node (which holds the system pods).

Which also explains why you can't use kubeadm on GKE - it's not meant for that purpose (of creating and managing your own cluster).

If you intend on running and managing your own cluster use GCE as you mentioned in your question.

As for listing the system pods - try listing all pods using `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to see the system pods status.

Comment: thank for reply. actually I want to enable PodNodeSelector admission controller plugin. is this impossible when using GKE? I want to setup like this https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podnodeselector

Comment: This feature is not included in GKE since it's a managed version of Kubernetes and the admission controllers for that feature aren't enabled.